# Flex SQLite Display SUM() result

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I try to display the Total sum() from a sqlStmt but all i got is [object, object], any idea how?

Thanks

```
private function displayAmountHeading():void  {
        sqlStmt = new SQLStatement();
        sqlStmt.sqlConnection = sqlConn;
        sqlStmt.text = "SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM MainTable";
        sqlStmt.execute();
        var result:Array = sqlStmt.getResult().data;
        if (result != null) trace(result);
      }

//return [object, object]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to trace an array. If you want to see the first value in that array, try

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) as sum FROM MainTable

trace(result[0].sum);
```

Comment: the result is still : [object Object], (even try result[1])

Comment: @jameslcs try what I changed my answer to.

Answer (score 2):

The object,object is the string representation of the object, without a toString() method. Use *trace(ObjectUtil.toString(result));* If your new to the flex sqlStatement you should also read [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLStatement.html) and [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLResult.html)
for more information about the return type of the sqlStatement and how to access properties of the result object, when using aggregate functions such as *SUM*, where u should use aliases, such as SUM(Amount) as sumAmount to later access the property, like resultObject["sumAmount"] or resultObject.sumAmount